# crontable OR conditions

Tags: cron

Crontable parameters seem to function as 'ands' conditions.  So the example

```
0 9-5 * * 1-5
```

Runs when the conditions are met "minute is zero AND hour is between 9 and 5 AND day is between monday and friday".

What I'd like is an 'or' function, so I can say "run monday to friday OR the 8th day of the month".  Does such a thing exist?

I realise you could add two entries, but with lots of entries it adds something to forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was gonna say: use `,` (comma). From `man 5 crontab`:

```
Lists are allowed.
A list is a set of numbers  (or  ranges)  separated  by  commas.
Examples:  "1,2,5,9","0-4,8-12".
```

But your case is slightly more complicated, and you can take advantage of this feature:

```
Note: The day of  a command's execution can be specified by two fields day
of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *),
the command will be run when either  field matches the current time.
For example, "30  4  1,15  *  5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am
on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.
```

So in your case, you can write `0 9-5 8 * 1-5`. That would run your command every 8th of the month and every day from Monday to Friday.

Another solution is to use a `test` (`man bash`, section CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, and `man date`):

```
# Run on every second Saturday of the month:
   0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```